# Unevaluated inline code with formula using \Sexpr{} in knitr

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I like using `\Sexpr{''}` for inline R code including highlighting. However, this does not seem to work for formulas. It seems like the tilde is a problem. It just doesn't show in the pdf.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<setup, echo=FALSE>>=
library("knitr")

knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) { 
  if (is.numeric(x)) return(knitr:::format_sci(x, 'latex')) 
  highr:::hi_latex(x) 
}) 
@

\Sexpr{'plot(x, y)'} works.

\Sexpr{'lm(response ~ treatment, data)'} does not show the tilde.

\end{document}
```

What I get is the following:

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closer at the results of the inline function you define in setup:

```
inline('lm(response ~ treatment, data)')

"[1]  \\hlkwd{lm}\\hlstd{(response} \\hlopt{~} \\hlstd{treatment, data)}"
```

There are two issues here: the tilde is flagged with \hlopt{} instead of \hlstd{}, and it is not properly marked as a symbol for LaTeX.  To do that, you need to insert it as `\textasciitilde`.

I don't know if there is a way to modify `highr::hi_latex` to interpret all mathematical symbols like the tilde properly.  Short of that, you can modify the LaTeX output *post facto* as follows:

```
<<setup, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) { 
  if (is.numeric(x)) return(knitr:::format_sci(x, 'latex')) 
  highr:::hi_latex(x) %>% 
    str_replace("~", "\\\\textasciitilde") %>% 
    str_replace("hlopt", "hlstd")
  }) 
@
```

Comment: What I ended up doing is to use `highr:::hi_latex(x) %>%  str_replace("hlopt", "textalltt")` with the textalltt definition from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70652/alltt-packages-alltt-makes-a-newline). That ends up doing exactly what I was hoping for. Your help definetly got me there. Thanks!